# How to make a status bar transparent in a dialog fragment?

Tags: android, xml, android-dialogfragment

I want to make my status bar and navigation bar transparent (not translucent).

```
<style name="FullScreenDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
</style>
```

I have tried a number of different combinations but none seem to work. This current setup gives me a black status bar background. I'm sure I'm missing something simple. I have also tried using:

```
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

On my layouts.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Why do you want to make the system bars transparent for a dialog? As the dialog will not fill the window.

Comment: I doubt these attributes will work for a dialog theme. for what you are trying to achieve`<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>`.  These must be applied not a dialog but to the whole app

Comment: Cheers for the responses, @sitatech it's a custom dialog so it fills full screen

Comment: @GeekDroid dwill this not just make the bars translucent?